# Word for "background works"

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word to describe complicated *background works*, *internal works* or *behind-the-scenes works*? These works are complicated and often people wouldn't want to know about it. An example is the complicated internal processes of a machine. All the phrases mentioned sound awkward and long.

Comment: Probably, 'dirty work' or 'back-office'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've heard most often of avoiding the **gruesome details**.

Comment: I've only ever heard "gory details".

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be *inner workings* (or possibly *internals*).

Comment: I like your answer, but I think that xenon was referring to different word.

Comment: @Carlo_R. could you elaborate on how my answer doesn't fit xEnOn's question?

Comment: Probably xEnOn was referring to a word or phrase to describe something complicated, difficult to understand. It does not seem that 'internals' has this meaning.

Comment: How about *inner workings*, which is my first choice?

Comment: The inner work takes a little practice - doing and 'undoing' - before one feels comfortable with it. It does not seem that xEnOn was referring to similar situation.

Answer (score 3):

The *nuts and bolts* of a machine or system refer to its internal workings.

*Skunkworks* (or *skunk works*) refers to works being carried out by people in a more or less secret manner, behind the scenes and unofficially.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're talking about **"backstage"** stuff.

Answer (score 2):

If you want something catchy and don't mind a degree of informality, you could use *nitty-gritty*.

Answer (score 2):

*[Infrastructure](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/infrastructure)* ("An underlying base or foundation; ... basic facilities, services and installations ...") is sometimes used to denote the foundations, underpinnings, and inner workings suggested in the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want some conciseness and informal tone is okay, you will entirely get the message across with *guts*.

Answer (score 1):

The answer could be "working in the trenches".

As Merriam Webster say "... or level at which an activity is carried on in a manner likened to trench warfare - often used in the phrase «activists working in the trenches»".

Comment: Your answer implies that the work is physically difficult or unpleasant.  What I think the OP is after is a word or phrase to describe something *complicated*.  That is, difficult to *understand*.

Comment: @John Y - You are right. Andrew's answer is the better answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think *mechanics* would work for what you describe.

*Mechanics* is defined as the working parts of a machine; or the technical aspects of something; or the functional aspect of a system, such as "the mechanics of blood circulation."